# Microsoft Graph API mail get quarantine messages c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API in order to try and get all quarantine emails messages for a user, but unfortunately the results are not correct.

Instead of getting back just the quarantine messages the endpoint returns back all the emails for the specified user.

I am just wondering if its even possible to achieve this as on their documentation there is nothing mentioning quarantined email messages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview

This is my function

```
 public static async Task<List<string>> GetQuarantineEmailsForUser(string userEmail)
 {
     try
     {
         var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

         var graphApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
         var quarantinedEmailsUrl = $"{graphApiUrl}users/{userEmail}/mailFolders/quarantine/childFolders/Inbox/messages";

         var today = DateTime.Today.AddHours(-1);
         var todayIso8601 = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"); // Format with timezone offset
         var filter = $"receivedDateTime ge {todayIso8601}";

         using (var client = new HttpClient())
         {
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
             var response = await client.GetAsync($"{quarantinedEmailsUrl}?$filter={filter}");

             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                 var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 var emails = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailListResponse>(responseContent);

                 List<string> emailSubjects = new List<string>();
                 foreach (var email in emails.value)
                 {
                     emailSubjects.Add(email.subject);
                 }

                 return emailSubjects;
             }
             else
             {
                 // Handle the error appropriately
                 throw new Exception($"Request failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Handle the exception appropriately in your application
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> var quarantinedEmailsUrl = $"{graphApiUrl}users/{userEmail}/mailFolders/quarantine/childFolders/Inbox/messages";

This isn't valid while it returns its more a bug as it just returns the Inbox folder rather than an error eg if you substitute anything in place of quarantine it will still return a valid context eg

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/barneythedinosaur/childfolders/inbox

will return

[image]

That looks like a bug in their parser as it's just mapping to the normal inbox, the new user quarantine is very sparsely documented but it uses a few folder under the Non_IPM_Subtree which are effectively hidden from the user. If you use the EWSEditor or MFCMapi you should be able to see them eg

[image]

They appear to have Wellknownfolder mapping so paths like

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/QedcShortRetention

and

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/QuarantinedEmailDefaultCategory

are returning the correct FolderId's and Message Counts. Whether this is a supported method of accessing the quarantined messages I'm not sure so it's possible you could loose access to this method in the future.

Comment: Hi Glen many thanks for your reply, i used postman to browse on those paths and you are correct those folders exists, but i would expect the quarantine messages to be in any of those 4 folders. Unfortunately those folders are empty in my case.

Would you know if there would be any other path or location that i could try out?